# Create a view with alternate/default values for missing relationships

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, view

In a setup that has several one-to-many relationships of objects, and each using a name attribute coming from a separate table. For example

```
Building(BuildingName), Floor(FloorName)
```

If a building has 2 names (2 languageIDs) and 5 floors, where only 3 floors have names for both language IDs, I want still to have 10 resulting entries. The floor names, where they are missing when the language id is missing, being pulled(defaulted) from non-matching floor id.

Comment: I have no idea what you really want, although I suspect you may be looking for an `OUTER JOIN` of some sort. Can you post sample data from both tables and your expected query results? A self-contained script that can copied and pasted directly into SSMS would be ideal.

Comment: An `OUTER JOIN` will give you the rows that you want.  The `COALESCE` function will allow you to substitute a default value for any missing (NULL) values that are returned by the join.  Providing sample data and desired results would result in more detailed responses.

Comment: I've been looking at the `COALESCE' function, but I'm sill trying to figure it out in this context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this along the right lines for what you're after?

Runnable example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/894e9/4

```
if object_id('[FloorName]') is not null drop table [FloorName]
if object_id('[BuildingName]') is not null drop table [BuildingName]
if object_id('[Floor]') is not null drop table [Floor]
if object_id('[Building]') is not null drop table [Building]
if object_id('[Language]') is not null drop table [Language]

create table [Language]
(
    Id bigint not null identity(1,1) primary key clustered
    , code nvarchar(5)
)
create table [Building]
(
    Id bigint not null identity(1,1) primary key clustered
    , something nvarchar(64)
)
create table [Floor]
(
    Id bigint not null identity(1,1) primary key clustered
    , BuildingId bigint foreign key references [Building](Id)
    , something nvarchar(64)
)
create table [BuildingName]
(
    Id bigint not null identity(1,1) primary key clustered
    , BuildingId bigint foreign key references [Building](Id)
    , LanguageId bigint foreign key references [Language](Id)
    , name nvarchar(64)
)
create table [FloorName]
(
    Id bigint not null identity(1,1) primary key clustered
    , FloorId bigint foreign key references [Floor](Id)
    , LanguageId bigint foreign key references [Language](Id)
    , name nvarchar(64)
)

insert [Language]
      select 'en-us'
union select 'en-gb'
union select 'fr'

insert [Building]
      select 'B1'
union select 'B2'

insert [Floor]
      select 1, 'F1.1'
union select 1, 'F1.2'
union select 1, 'F1.3'
union select 1, 'F1.4'
union select 1, 'F1.5'
union select 2, 'F2.1'
union select 2, 'F2.2'
union select 2, 'F2.3'
union select 2, 'F2.4'
union select 2, 'F2.5'

insert BuildingName
select b.Id
, l.id
, 'BuildingName :: ' + b.something + ' ' + l.code
from [Building] b
cross join [Language] l
where l.code in ('en-us', 'fr')

insert FloorName
select f.Id
, l.Id
, 'FloorName :: ' + f.something + ' ' + l.code
from [Floor] f
cross join [Language] l
where f.something in ( 'F1.1', 'F1.2', 'F2.1')
and l.code in ('en-us', 'fr')

insert FloorName
select  f.Id
, l.Id
, 'FloorName :: ' + f.something + ' ' + l.code
from [Floor] f
cross join [Language] l
where f.something not in ( 'F1.1', 'F1.2', 'F2.1')
and l.code in ('en-us')


declare @defaultLanguageId bigint
select @defaultLanguageId = id from [Language] where code = 'en-us' --default language is US English

select b.Id
, b.something
, bn.name
, isnull(bfn.name, bfnDefault.name)
, bl.code BuildingLanguage
from [Building] b
inner join [BuildingName] bn
    on bn.BuildingId = b.Id
inner join [Language] bl
    on bl.Id = bn.LanguageId
inner join [Floor] bf
    on bf.BuildingId = b.Id
left outer join [FloorName] bfn
    on bfn.FloorId = bf.Id
    and bfn.LanguageId = bl.Id
left outer join [Language] bfl
    on bfl.Id = bfn.LanguageId
left outer join [FloorName] bfnDefault
    on bfnDefault.FloorId = bf.Id
    and bfnDefault.LanguageId = @defaultLanguageId
```

**EDIT**

This version defaults any language:

```
select b.Id
, b.something
, bn.name
, isnull(bfn.name, (select top 1 name from [FloorName] x where x.FloorId=bf.Id))
, bl.code BuildingLanguage
from [Building] b
inner join [BuildingName] bn
    on bn.BuildingId = b.Id
inner join [Language] bl
    on bl.Id = bn.LanguageId
inner join [Floor] bf
    on bf.BuildingId = b.Id
left outer join [FloorName] bfn
    on bfn.FloorId = bf.Id
    and bfn.LanguageId = bl.Id
left outer join [Language] bfl
    on bfl.Id = bfn.LanguageId
```

Comment: Is it possible to default to french when the English entry is missing?

Comment: Yes - to check how to you want the default language to be determined - should it just pick any language available for the given floor, any of the languages available to the building, or specific subset of default languages with a priority list?

Comment: just any works, basically I'm just trying to avoid null values in the names

Comment: No worries, try the updated code at the end (SQLFiddle link also updated to show both versions of the code)